# Loggers not created while a file running through QUARTZ scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have implemented quartz scheduler in my application. And its working upto a certain point. After that its giving exception. When i check the logs in loggers they are also not generated. Its perfectly running on my local server but not on the server where the application is deployed. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is your logger configured? Is it that the log files are not generated? Or the error not being logged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are log variables null?

If so, try to declare them static final, such as:

```
private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

Quartz can serialize the classes you use, so you run into serialization/deserialization issues. However, if it is the case, can't be determined as long you don't provide code and configuration samples.

Answer (score 0):

About the logging for quartz, please check configurations for the logging tool you use. If you have not see any logs so this may be a configuration problem because all logging stuff is mainly configuration related.

What kind of exception does quartz give? Or maybe you can't see it due to logging? :)

Comment: On local server its running fine. But on the server on which it is deployed is not generating logs. And I cant see what exception is thrown at runtime as logs are not generated.

Comment: Hmm that's strange. What do you use for local and deployment server?